# How to move curve after rotating it in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt5, rotation, pyqtgraph

The question is following on a previous question:
[Rotate curves in place in pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77221100/rotate-curves-in-place-in-pyqtgraph)

The curves are rotating now, but I can't move it afterwards, it's jumping back to its previous position before the rotation.
Moving it and then rotating it from there is no problem.

This is my test code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QTransform
import numpy as np


class CurveViewer(QMainWindow):

    scaling_factors = {'x': 0.0000001, 'y': 1.0}

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Curve Viewer")

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        # Create a GraphicsLayoutWidget to hold the plot
        self.graph_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.graph_widget)

        # Create sliders for controlling the selected curve
        self.slider_x = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider_x.setRange(-1000, 1000)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider_x)

        self.slider_y = QSlider(Qt.Vertical)
        self.slider_y.setRange(-10000, 10000)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider_y)

        self.slider_rotation = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider_rotation.setRange(-180, 180)  # Angle range in degrees
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider_rotation)

        # Create a single PlotItem to hold all curves
        self.plot_item = self.graph_widget.addPlot()
        self.curves = []
        self.curve_data = []  # Store initial curve data
        self.offsets = []  # Store offsets for each curve
        self.rotations = []  # Store rotations for each curve

        # Create example plot data with multiple curves
        num_curves = 3
        for i in range(num_curves):
            x_data = np.linspace(0, 0.00008, 100)
            y_data = np.linspace(1000, 6000, 100) + i * 1000
            pen = pg.mkPen(color=pg.intColor(i), width=1.0)
            curve_item = self.plot_item.plot(x_data, y_data, pen=pen, clickable=True)
            curve_item.setCurveClickable(True)
            curve_item.sigClicked.connect(self.__handle_curve_click)
            self.curves.append(curve_item)
            self.curve_data.append((x_data, y_data))
            self.offsets.append((0, 0))  # Initialize offsets to zero
            self.rotations.append(0)  # Initialize rotations to zero

        # Store the currently clicked curve
        self.clicked_curve = None

        # Copy the original data for all curves
        self.original_curve_data = self.curve_data.copy()

        # Connect slider valueChanged signals to slot functions
        self.slider_x.valueChanged.connect(self.update_curve_position)
        self.slider_y.valueChanged.connect(self.update_curve_position)
        self.slider_rotation.valueChanged.connect(self.update_curve_rotation)

    def __handle_curve_click(self, curve_item):
        # Reset the pen properties of all curves to the default thickness
        for curve in self.curves:
            pen = curve.opts['pen']
            pen = pg.mkPen(pen)
            default_pen = pg.mkPen(color=pen.color(), width=1.0)
            curve.setPen(default_pen)

        # Modify the pen properties of the selected curve to make it thicker
        pen = curve_item.opts['pen']
        pen = pg.mkPen(pen)
        selected_pen = pg.mkPen(color=pen.color(), width=2.0)
        curve_item.setPen(selected_pen)

        self.clicked_curve = curve_item

        # Set slider values to match the current offset and rotation of the clicked curve
        x_offset, y_offset = self.offsets[self.curves.index(self.clicked_curve)]
        rotation = self.rotations[self.curves.index(self.clicked_curve)]

        self.slider_x.setValue(int(x_offset / self.scaling_factors['x']))
        self.slider_y.setValue(int(y_offset / self.scaling_factors['y']))
        self.slider_rotation.setValue(int(rotation))

    def update_curve_position(self):
        if self.clicked_curve is not None:
            x_offset = self.slider_x.value() * self.scaling_factors['x']
            y_offset = self.slider_y.value() * self.scaling_factors['y']
            index = self.curves.index(self.clicked_curve)
            x_data, y_data = self.curve_data[index]

            # Update the offset for the clicked curve
            self.offsets[index] = (x_offset, y_offset)

            # Then apply the translation (offset) transformation with scaling factors
            translated_x_data = [x + x_offset for x in x_data]
            translated_y_data = [y + y_offset for y in y_data]

            # Update the data for the clicked curve
            self.clicked_curve.setData(translated_x_data, translated_y_data)

    def update_curve_rotation(self):
        if self.clicked_curve is not None:
            rotation_degrees = self.slider_rotation.value()
            index = self.curves.index(self.clicked_curve)
            x_data, y_data = self.curve_data[index]
            x_offset, y_offset = self.offsets[index]

            # Update the rotation for the clicked curve
            self.rotations[index] = rotation_degrees

            # Apply both the translation (offset) and rotation transformations
            rotation_matrix = QTransform().rotate(rotation_degrees)
            rotated_x_data, rotated_y_data = [], []

            x_range, y_range = self.plot_item.getViewBox().viewRange()
            x_size = x_range[1] - x_range[0]
            y_size = y_range[1] - y_range[0]

            for x, y in zip(x_data / x_size, y_data / y_size):
                rotated_point = rotation_matrix.map(QPointF(x, y))
                rotated_x_data.append(rotated_point.x() * x_size)
                rotated_y_data.append(rotated_point.y() * y_size)

            # Update the offset for the clicked curve
            self.offsets[index] = (x_offset, y_offset)

            translated_x_data = [x + x_offset for x in rotated_x_data]
            translated_y_data = [y + y_offset for y in rotated_y_data]

            # Update the data for the clicked curve
            self.clicked_curve.setData(translated_x_data, translated_y_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    viewer = CurveViewer()
    viewer.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I figured out that QTransform is rotating it around a certain axis, so not its current position. (Always moving away and not staying at its place) In this case the offset is also changing but of course not updating it.
Still struggle to find a proper solution. I tried to find the center of the curve and make it the rotation point but that's also not quite working. Not sure if I also have to take care of the scaling factors, but I guess not. The translated data looks fine.

In conclusion:

I want to rotate the curve around the center such that it looks like it's rotating in its current position, then being able to also move it in a rotated way.

Comment: Can you please edit your post with the code in form of a complete and self-contained [mre], so that we don't need to put pieces together from different posts?